# How do I determine Windows Version and Service Pack from WindowsUpdateLog.txt

Tags: windows, service-pack

I have a copy of the windowsupdatelog.txt from another computer. I wonder whether or not its possible to determine the version of windows and service pack level is installed on the machine.
The file includes the following version information as far as I can tell:

```
22.09.2009 07:02:50:875 168 10c Report    * OS Version = 5.1.2600.3.0.66304
```

I have found out that 5.1.2600 is windows XP but can I determine which service pack it is? Does the 5.1.2600 version denote a specific service pack or is this version common for all service packs?

#### Followup Question:

I suspected that the 3.0 part meant SP3 which was confirmed by John T.
Does this mean that version 2.0, 1.0 and 0.0 means SP2, SP1 and no service pack respectively also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Windows XP build 2600 SP3.

5.1 - NT Version

2600 - Build Number

3.0 - Service Pack