# windows command line: can I tell Service pack number?

Tags: windows, command-line, service-pack

Is there is a way to get service pack number from command line? Or the build number from command line (from which I can tell the service pack number (see [How do I determine Windows Version and Service Pack from WindowsUpdateLog.txt](https://superuser.com/questions/61944/how-do-i-determine-windows-version-and-service-pack-from-windowsupdatelog-txt)))?

Upon starting `cmd`, part of the Windows version number is shown on the screen, but not the service pack number.

I prefer a non-PowerShell answer, but I wouldn't mind knowing about a PowerShell answer anyways since some computers I deal with do have it installed.

Comment: Other related websites: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29718402/how-to-check-service-packs-on-remote-computers.aspx and 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279631

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"`

Source: [Find windows version from command prompt](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/)

Comment: This is the only one that works on all computers I've tried these methods on.

Comment: ps - the above only works if the user language is English, since the string filter uses the English names.  Using systeminfo on its own will work for any language - though requires manual effort searching through all the data returned.

Answer (score 10):

You can get it using WMIC - **`wmic os get servicepackmajorversion`**

For more on using WMIC, see this little tutorial:
http://quux.wiki.zoho.com/WMIC-Snippets.html

Comment: Is wmic installed on all Windows computers? for some reason, my home computer does not recognize `wmic`.

Comment: Awesome tool, thanks for sharing! @Thr4wn, according to Wikipedia, WMIC is not available on Windows XP Home Edition, but is available on XP Pro and all later versions of Windows.

Answer (score 6):

You can type in CMD:

> Winver

Comment: nice answer! .... +1 when i get more votes

Comment: Hm... problem with that is, it opens a GUI tool, which may not be what the user is attempting to do.

Comment: SYSTEMINFO run in a command prompt will display without GUI.

Comment: In `cmd.exe` you can use just `ver` and get the version on stdout. But you need to convert the build number to get the SP.

Comment: `ver` doesn't give the full version number. It stops right before the service pack number.

Comment: And nhinkle is correct, I am looking for a way that doesn't involve GUI at all. Specifically I'm running `psexec \\computer cmd` and then wanting a command to give me the service pack number.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the command line by querying the registry for the ServicePack key. If an SP is installed, it will be shown, otherwise, it will say that it was unable to locate the specified key, in which case there is no service pack.

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ServicePack
```

Comment: This only works if there is a Service Pack installed (e.g. currently Windows 7 does not have a Service Pack so the key does not exist)

Comment: I know; that's what I stated in my answer. If the key doesn't exist, then there is no service pack, thus it is SP0. If the key does exist, it'll tell you the service pack. So either way, you can figure out what service pack (if any) is installed.

Comment: When I try Giri's solution, it shows SP 3, but this method reports that it was unable to find the specified registry key or value (I copied/pasted the command into cmd).

Comment: Instead of "ServicePack", you can use "ProductName" and "CSDVersion"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
wmic os get csdversion /format:value
```